# Accessing Upload Image in Server Side

Tags: node.js, angularjs

I am supposed to upload image & store it in GridFS. My problem here is I am not getting selected image by user on server side.

```
<input type="file" name="letterhead" />
```

Server Side

```
console.log(req.files);
```

It shows me undefined.

Comment: are u doing form post or ajax post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you tagged it as AngularJS so I assume you use the file input inside AngularJS controller. As far as I'm aware ngModel doesn't work on file inputs. I personally do it this way

```
<input type="file" id="uploadImage" name="uploadImage" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().setFiles(this)">
```

and then in controller

```
$scope.setFiles = function (element) {
        $scope.$apply(function () {
            $scope.file = element.files[0];
            //from now on you can do whatever you want with your image $scope.file
        });
    };
```